# Range check logic?

Tags: if-statement, vb6

How do I code this in VB6. I almost got it already but I don't know how to put it all together. I am doing this in VB6.

```
If Incometxt >= 20962 Then StatusLbl = "Low-income class"
ElseIf Incometxt <= 20963 Then StatusLbl = "Lower middle-income class"
ElseIf Incometxt <= 41925 Then StatusLbl = "Middle middle-income class"
ElseIf Incometxt <= 73368 Then StatusLbl = "Upper middle-income class"
ElseIf Incometxt <= 125773 && = 2096200 Then StatusLbl = "Upper-income class"
Else Incometxt > 2096201 Then StatusLbl = "Rich"
```

I think the mistake happened on line 5 and 6 of the code I gave above.

Comment: You would be well-advised to look into the Select Case structure. It's designed for just this sort of situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
If Incometxt <= 20962 Then
    StatusLbl = "Low-income class"
ElseIf Incometxt >= 20963 And Incometxt <= 41924 Then
    StatusLbl = "Lower middle-income class"
ElseIf Incometxt >= 41925 And Incometxt <= 73367 Then
    StatusLbl = "Middle middle-income class"
ElseIf Incometxt >= 73368 And Incometxt <= 125772 Then
    StatusLbl = "Upper middle-income class"
ElseIf Incometxt >= 125773 And Incometxt <= 2096200 Then
    StatusLbl = "Upper-income class"
Else
    StatusLbl = "Rich"
End If
```

Comment: First, you don't need to repeat every limit. If you've already established that the income is not less than or equal to 20962, it's a given that it's above that. Same with every bracket. Second, it's wasteful to compare numeric values as text. Convert `IncomeTxt` to a `Long` and compare those.

Comment: @Jim Mack I agree, left side of every AND expression is redundant.